# How can I add transition animation on CollectionView cell?

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have *CollectionView* and each cell go to new controller. In ***(_ collectionView:, didSelectItemAt indexPath:)*** function execute that code :

```
    if case datagelen.itemTitleLabel = "Takım" {
        let homecon = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
        let dataGelen = itemler[indexPath.item]
        homecon.name = dataGelen.itemTitleLabel!
        homecon.imageDenemeHome = dataGelen.image!
        homecon.takimCell()
    }
```

It controls cells and send to Parent ViewController to navigate new Controller. In Parent ViewController this code will execute:

```
func takimCell() {
    let detailvc = takimCellDetail()
    detailvc.nameForDetail = name
    detailvc.imageDetail = imageDenemeHome
    let top = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: detailvc)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    top?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And after that code execute `takimCellDetail` controller open and system work but in this point I have a problem I wrote that code when I just started swift and programming so it is not good at this time. Is there any other way to improve that because I want to use `pushViewController()` method. Or how can I add transition animation ?
Sorry about my english. I hope I can explain my question.

Comment: So what do you want to do? Transition, code improving? Or something doesn't work here? Can you share more code and clearly write what doesn't work, work as not expected or what doesn't clear for you. Thx! :-)

Comment: Accutally I want to add navigationController on detail controllers which is open when collectionView cell tapped. In here I open these controllers with shared key window but I think it is not very clear way to do that.

Comment: You need to replace top?... on self. . It will just show new navigation cotroller in popup mode

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear.
There is different ways to get access of a controller and its elements.

```
let homecon = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
```

If you want only class reference to access elements then you can write it as  -

```
let homecon = HomeController()
```

I am trying to shares some piece of code using *CollectionView* and navigation to other *Controllers* on *cell/Item* click.

```
func takimCell() {
    let detailvc = takimCellDetail()
    detailvc.nameForDetail = name
    detailvc.imageDetail = imageDenemeHome
    detailvc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(detailvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```